# C++ shared object initialization constructor destructor

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-libraries

I'm working on a Shared Object compiled with `g++` that serves as a logging API. I've written a little utility to exercise the library, but I've found that the shared object constructor/destructor are called every time the program starts and exits. I'd like to be able to maintain the state of any variables/objects in the `.so` file, even if there are no active applications linked. Is there a mechanism for accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to be able to maintain the state of any variables/objects in the .so file, even if there are no active applications linked. Is there a mechanism for accomplishing this?

In a modern OS, *everything* that is in memory "belongs" to one or more processes, and there is no such thing as "`.so` without an active application".

In addition, when your `.so` is linked into several active applications (running processes), there is *still* no shared state that your library can record -- each instance of your `.so` will have no way of observing that other instances of that `.so` are active in other processes, except by using some `IPC` mechanism.

You *could* create a shared memory segment using [shmat](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shmat.3p.html), and record shared state there. That state would also persist until explicitly removed via [smtctl](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shmctl.3p.html) system call.

Beware: using shared memory this way is fraught with complications, and is very likely an overkill for a logging API library.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I did try using the shared memory method you'd mentioned, but the logging library I'm wrapping makes heavy use of `shared_ptr`s. So if one process created a sink, and another dereferences said sink..... segfault. Might just have to abandon the system level goal and have the API behave as it does currently